# Assign dataframe to variable outside for loop or use it directly inside for loop in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, performance

option 1:

```
a = np.unique(df.values)
for i in range():
  if df2.loc[i,'col1'] in a:
    df2.loc[i,'col2'] = 'Ok'
  else:
    df2.loc[i,'col2'] = 'No'
```

option 2:

```
for i in range():
  if df2.loc[i,'col1'] in np.unique(df.values):
    df2.loc[i,'col2'] = 'Ok'
  else:
    df2.loc[i,'col2'] = 'No'
```

Which is better in terms of memory and speed in Python?

Edited for clarity on the operation inside the for loop.

Comment: Probably neither. But we have no clue what "something" is, and this is highly relevant.

Comment: I added the code inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are inefficient, the second is the worse as you recalculate the unique values at each step.

Use vectorial code instead:

```
df2['col2'] = df2['col1'].isin(np.unique(df.values)).map({True: 'Ok', False: 'No'})
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of memory, option 2 would be probably be better because you aren't making a new variable. In terms of speed, there wouldn't be a difference because they `df.values` and `a` refer to the same piece of data. You can see if two variables refer to the same piece of data by using the is keyword: `var1 is var2`. However, we don't know what you are doing with the data.

Comment: what do you mean by *you aren't making a new variable*?, the variable is being generated the first loop and it is reasigning the value all the next iterations, am i wrong?

Comment: I added the code I want to use.

Comment: There wouldn't be a difference with the code you're using. In option 1, they are making a new variable: a. By making a variable, you are making the code shorter.